# How to solve 'GLOG_logtostderr' not recongnised error in window?

Tags: windows, glog, mediapipe

When I am trying to run **mediapipe hand-tracking on cmd in windows** it is throwing this error: **'GLOG_logtostderr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

Here's the snapshot of cmd:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhcgN.png)

Comment: provide more details or some code

Comment: @G.Dimov I have added a snapshot of the cmd.